# data.csv - appending to new line in CSV (clojure)

Tags: csv, clojure

I have been testing out this csv package [data.csv](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv).

I have managed to make the writing to CSV work. I am still very new to clojure/lisp.

What I cannot figure out (through testing or via the documentation), is how to add the data too a new line in the csv.

The API documentation says this:

```
write-csv
function
Usage: (write-csv writer data & options)
Writes data to writer in CSV-format.

Valid options are
  :separator (Default \,)
  :quote (Default \")
  :quote? (A predicate function which determines if a string should be quoted. Defaults to quoting only when necessary.)
  :newline (:lf (default) or :cr+lf)
```

But i cannot workout how to use it this.

I am trying to add a new line for the following code:

```
(defn writeCSV [name]
  (with-open [writer (io/writer filePath)]
    (csv/write-csv writer
                 [[name 2]])))
```

Where the `name` is added to the next available line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:append` option of `io/writer`:

```clj
(require
  '[clojure.data.csv :as csv] 
  '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(with-open [writer (io/writer "/tmp/foo.csv" :append true)] 
  (csv/write-csv writer [["name" 1]]))
(with-open [writer (io/writer "/tmp/foo.csv" :append true)] 
  (csv/write-csv writer [["name" 2]]))

(println (slurp "/tmp/foo.csv"))
;;=>
name,1
name,2
```

Comment: im curious, where would I go to find this out myself? `:append` is not mentioned in the docs for data.csv.

Comment: The `:append` is a property of `io/writer` so would not be in the docs for `data.csv`.  The options are not (but should be) in the docs at https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.io/writer  But one of the examples there does show the `:append` option.

Comment: I really enjoy clojure but im starting to feel the pain of "not enough clear docs". Thanks @dorab

Comment: By the way, the options are documented at https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.io/IOFactory  Not an obvious location, I'll admit.